# Would a trigger be more efficient in this situation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an instance where we have a primary record and several related tables.  In this scenario we keep all historical records in the related tables.  So in this situation it would look like this

```
Main Table - Visits
ID
Date
CurrentRoomHistoryID
CurrentStatusHistoryID

Related Table - RoomHistory
ID
Name
StartDate
EndDate

Related Table - StatusHistory
ID 
StatusID
StartDate
EndDate
```

For speeds sake you can see we keep the ID of the current room and history in the main table.  Right now when either gets updated I set the end date for the previous room or status record, then update the main table.

Would it be faster and more efficient to have a `TRIGGER` that adds the end date to the previous record and updates the main table?

Comment: "more efficient" - than what?

Comment: Than running separate queries from the application to update the main table and the related records in the status and room history tables.

Comment: more importantly: a trigger will always run so perhaps the more correct place to be updating history

Comment: Bit like asking "how long is a piece of string?" - You would need to tell us exactly how the current operation works so that we can compare apples with apples. Having said that, most SQL developers will try to avoid triggers.

Comment: If they're to be avoided, I'll try to squeeze more performance elsewhere I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe efficiency would not depend as much on separate update queries or trigger as much it'd depend on how you filter the records to be updated. As a matter of fact, whatever you have in your update query would go into the trigger definition - probably with some minor changes.

As far as performance is concerned. your ID fields should be properly indexed in all the 3 tables.

A trigger might have been faster if you were updating something for the current record being updated or inserted. But since you are updating the previous room or status data, the seek and update would take the same time in trigger or update query.